# Fix iTunes Billing issue with iTunes code

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

My prepaid MasterCard didn't have enough value so a problem occurred at my last purchase and I can't download any already purchased music or free updates anymore as I have to update my credit card information. If I enter the prepaid data it says invalid because it does not have enough money on it, and due to holidays it will take another few days for my bank to transfer the money to it. Is it possible to fix this issue by redeeming an iTunes code (5€ for example?) or does it only work with a credit card?

Thanks for help! It's really important, have a new iMac 5k but can't download anythingn from the Mac app store or iTunes :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I purchased 10€ via Paypal and it worked well, after reedeming I had 9.11€ left :)